# How to set placeholder color different at different places in code

Tags: html, css

I am preparing a notes app, and as it contains a toggle dark/light mode I want the placeholder text (in a different location) to change accordingly.

Currently it changes in a certain component but doesn't change in the other.

The app:
[image: Notes App Screenshot]

Basically I want the top placeholder text to be white and the bottom highlighted one to remain as it is

This is the code in style.css which sets it to black:

```
::placeholder {
    color: #181818;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this :

: ClassName : : placeholder

```css
.name::placeholder
{
    color:red;
}
.fname::placeholder
{
    color:green;
}
.mname::placeholder
{
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="name" placeholder="Enter your Name" name=""></br>
<input type="text" class="fname" placeholder="Enter your father's Name" name=""></br>
<input type="text" class="mname" placeholder="Enter your mpther's Name" name=""></br>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible using different classes and targeting the elements accordingly

```
textarea.placeholder-red::placeholder {
  color: red;
}

textarea.placeholder-blue::placeholder {
  color: blue;
}
```

**Example**

```css
textarea.placeholder-red::placeholder {
  color: red;
}

textarea.placeholder-blue::placeholder {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="placeholder-red" placeholder="red placeholder text"></textarea>
<textarea class="placeholder-blue" placeholder="blue placeholder text"></textarea>
```

Comment: Tysm, this worked like a charm. Thanks for updating the answer with and example too <3